# Can I use an interface to accomplish this task?

Tags: vb.net, oop, inheritance, interface

Hi StackOverflow Community,

I have a specific situation dealing with Interfaces in VB.Net.

Particularly, I have one function that should be able to run for every child class the interface has. Here is a simple example:

```
Public Interface Book
   Function TurnPage() As Page
   Sub OpenBook()
   Sub CloseBook()
End Interface

Public Class Reader
   Public Sub Reading()
      OpenBook()
      TurnPage()
      CloseBook()
   End Sub
End Class

Public Class Magazine
   Implements Book

   Public Function TurnPage() As Page
     Implements Book.TurnPage
     ' Code implementation for TurnPage
   End Function

   Public Sub OpenBook()
     Implements Book.TurnPage
     ' Code implementation for OpenBook
   End Sub

   Public Sub CloseBook()
     Implements Book.TurnPage
     ' Code implementation for CloseBook
   End Sub
End Class

Public Class Novel
   Implements Book

   Public Function TurnPage() As Page
     Implements Book.TurnPage
     ' Code implementation for TurnPage
   End Function

   Public Sub OpenBook()
     Implements Book.TurnPage
     ' Code implementation for OpenBook
   End Sub

   Public Sub CloseBook()
     Implements Book.TurnPage
     ' Code implementation for CloseBook
   End Sub
End Class
```

How can I use the Sub in Reader(Reading) for all the child classes(Magazine and Novel) for that particular interface(Book)?

Comment: inheritance would seem more applicable than an interface.  Book, Magazine, Paperback etc would all turn the page the same way so that method could be implemented on `Class MustInherit Publication`.  An eBook class would then override TurnPage to do something only similar. Reader would invoke the method: `myRdr.thisMagazine.TurnPage`.  An interface would seem to be the choice when all the inherited classes were like eBook and had to do support a Method but implement it in its own way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change you `Reader` to accept a `Book`:

```
Public Class Reader
   Public BookToRead as Book  
   Public Sub New(ABook As Book)
      Me.BookToRead = ABook
   End Sub

   Public Sub Reading()
      BookToRead.OpenBook()
      BookToRead.TurnPage()
      BookToRead.CloseBook()
   End Sub
End Class
```

Then when you need a reader to read a book:

```
Dim ThreeMusketeers As New Novel()
Dim reader1 as New Reader(ThreeMusketeers) // Novel
reader1.Reading()

Dim NewYorkTimes As New Magazine()
Dim reader2 as New Reader(NewYorkTimes)
reader2.Reading()
```